# How to move around a 3D model in Vuforia Image Target?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I have been developing AR Apps using Unity 3D and Vuforia SDK. In our applications, the 3d models are being placed in a position in ImageTarget and the models are doing the animations in the same position only! How to  make 3D models to move around the image target? (i.e.,) Movement should be independent instead of being attached to a position!

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the translation of your object. It's independant from the animation. You could do something like this to your gameobject :

```
public float speed;

void Update () {
    this.transform.Translate(speed, 0, 0);
}
```

But it would simply make a translation of your gameobject once per frame on the x axis. If you would like to make it move like it is a player character, you should look at [this tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/survival-shooter/player-character?playlist=17144). If you are having problems while testing your movement, it's possible that would have to change Vuforia's camera settings.